# How do I make an iframe fit the entire screen without specifying dimensions?

Tags: html, iframe

If I don't specify any dimensions, the iframe appears tiny. If I do specify dimensions as follows then it does not properly scale for different screen resolutions

```
<iframe name="report"style="height:1200px;width:800px;">
```

Is there a way to automatically allow the iframe to stretch to the entire screen?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use %

```
<iframe name="report" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is not working for iframe inside a bootstrap modal

Comment: @NithinChandran Actually, it is. You are likely making the same mistake I originally did by assuming defining it in CSS would respond the same as hardcoding the actual iframe tag.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the `iframe` has no small ancestor with `position: relative`.

```
<iframe name="report"style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0: left: 0;">
```

You should also consider using an external stylesheet.

Comment: The iframe appears tiny now have I done something wrong? <iframe name="report" src="s.html" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0: left: 0;">

Comment: @deltanovember: Nope. Do you have a link to it live?

Comment: Unfortunately it's for internal use only

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;position: relative; height:200px;"  >
      <iframe class="" rel="nofollow" style="height: 800px; width:1400px; transform: scale(0.294167) !important; transform-origin: 0px 0px;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
      src="your iframe link"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what im looking for, even the question was not exactly about that